# creating walls for simple maze game

Tags: ios, iphone

i am doing a single view game demo, a maze like game with walls. player will control the character with a UIButton.

basically i have devised that i will need to check that if in the next step, the character is going to intersect with a wall, the character movement will return false. but, i cannot seem to put them together.

i currently have this boolean function to check if the character is going to intersect with the wall

```
-(Boolean) checkCollision : (CGRect) newFrame{
CGRect frame = self.mainchar.frame;
frame.origin.x = self.currentPoint.x;
frame.origin.y = self.currentPoint.y;

for (UIImageView *image in self.hardwalls) {

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(frame, image.frame)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

my UIButton for movement is

```
-(IBAction)CharMovingLeft:(id)sender; {
CGPointMake(mainchar.center.x -charmovement, mainchar.center.y);
```

what should i be adding into the button method so that it will stop this movement when the intersection is going to happen?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)CharMovingLeft:(id)sender {

    CGRect newFrame = YOUR_CHARACTERS_FRAME_IF_IT_MOVED;

    if (![self checkCollision:newFrame];
        //MOVE CHARACTER:

    }

    else 
        //DONT MOVE CHARACTER
}
```

Will this do ... ?